# Как сделать "СПИСОК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННЫХ ИСТОЧНИКОВ" в XeLaTeX по гост ГОСТ Р 7.0.5-2008 для нир по ГОСТ 7.32-2017?

Tags: latex, гост

Нужен оформленный правильно список источников по нынешнему госту для НИР.
Написал два варианта, но ни один не похож

```
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

[image: рисунок по первому примеру]

И второй вариант

```
\usepackage[% 
backend=biber, %подключение пакета biber (тоже нужен)
bibstyle=gost-numeric, %подключение одного из четырех главных стилей biblatex-gost 
citestyle=numeric-comp, %подключение стиля стиля (а вот!) 
language=auto, %указание сортировки языков
babel=other, %указание языков
sorting=ntvy, %тип сортировки в библиографии
doi=false, 
eprint=false, 
isbn=false, 
dashed=false, 
url=false %все false выключают отображение полей, заполненных в библиографической базе, но не актуальных для печатного листа
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %убирает с. и p. 
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % добавляет точку с запятой и пробел (; ) в перечислении
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} % добавляет двоеточие и пробел (: ) перед номером страницы
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=langid, match=russian, final]
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue={a}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=langid, notmatch=russian, final]
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue={z}]
    }
  }
}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian} %язык по умолчанию
\setotherlanguage{english}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

получается такое

[image: Второй вариант примера]

Нужно получить такой вариант, но не обязательно придерживаться, главное по госту, так как на рисунке почему-то нет точки после нумерация.
[image: нужный вариант]

Comment: Осталось убрать номер цифры в заголовке, что бы было без номера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

устанавливаем пакет ГОСТа

команды в консоль, внимание с расположением файлов, распаковать в окружение latexa

```
mkdir /tmp/gost && cd /tmp/gost
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/gost.zip
unzip gost.zip
sudo cp -r gost /usr/share/texmf/
sudo texhash
```

после в преамбуле

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind} %добавляет в содержание список источников
\makeatletter % |список 
\bibliographystyle{ugost2008} % |литературы
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}% |с \makeatother % |точкой
```

в самом документе оставляем ссылку с помощью

```
\cite{...}
```

после чего в нужном месте вызываем наш список источников

```
\renewcommand\refname{СПИСОК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННЫХ ИСТОЧНИКОВ}
\bibliography{bib}
```

Осталась проблема убрать номер в заголовке

[image: готовый список литературы]

Comment: а что, каталог `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/gost` из [texlive-lang-cyrillic](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/texlive-lang-cyrillic/filelist) содержит не то же самое, что вы предлагаете руками скачивать-распаковывать? (ещё gost упоминается в пакете [texlive-bibtex-extra](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/texlive-bibtex-extra)).

Comment: Понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду, эти пакеты не были установлены, следовательно не проверял. Предложите ваш ответ, которой был бы более правильный, без номера при заголовке и входил бы в содержание, наиболее рабочий вариант к НИР

Comment: я страшно далёк от всех этих библиографий/стандартов оформления и т.д. и т.п. // всего лишь уточнил, не эти ли самые файлы входят в указанный пакет: ведь установка готового пакета — однозначно предпочтительней ручного засорения системных каталогов.